# Drupal print block fields separately and not all rendered block

Tags: drupal, field, block

I have Drupal image block installed and want to print it's fields separately:
Title
Body
Image
I tried
module_invoke('imageblock', 'block_view', '1');
but it is printing all content rendered already

Answer (score 0):

Go for Bean module instead:

https://www.drupal.org/project/bean

With it you have total freedom to define block fields as you like and also you can make block template files as you like, display fields you want the way you want. Much, much more powerful module which you can use again and again for many different purposes.

That image block module doesn't include any template file that can be overridden, so it's created for some very basic use case I guess.

Comment: Thanks you..was helpful much

Comment: Please mark as it answered your question or at least vote up if it helped you.